# Can not set proper resolution on this one monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, resolution, xrandr, intel-hd

I have a laptop with Intel HD graphics and running on `Linux trusty 3.13.0-45-generic`.

I never had problems connecting external displays to my Display Port, but now I got a new monitor and can not get my laptop to output the proper resolution.

The display is the [Asus ROG Swift PG278Q](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/ROG_SWIFT_PG278Q/specifications/).

When I run `xrandr`, all I get for the Display Port is

```
DP1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

Then I tried to add the proper mode manually, so I ran:

```
$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Then added the mode:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP1 "2560x1440_60.00"
```

Upon activating the mode with

```
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
```

All I see on the display is the message

```
OUT OF RANGE
```

I also tried other resolutions and refresh rates with no success. On an other display my laptop manages 2560x1440p60 without problems. This particular monitor also works in this mode on a windows machine of mine.

Any suggestions on how to solve or debug this?

Answer (score 3):

Alright, i figured it out myself.

Using the [Monitor Asset Manager](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm) I could determine a functioning ModeLine for that Monitor, which is:

```
"2560x1440@60" 241,500 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
```

Comment: Thank you! The correct mode line for this particular monitor was very difficult for me to find elsewhere